# Laravel blade hardcode variable on compile

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm moving some of my view strings to config because I want to use the same code for similar sites, and I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid a call to Config:: or Lang:: on every runtime.

```
<h1>{{ Config::get('siteName') }}</h1>
```

blade makes in into

```
<h1><?php echo Config::get('siteName'); ?></h1>
```

But I want it to be just plain HTML like

```
<h1>MySite</h1>
```

My approach is trying to make this when Blade compiles the views into plain PHP / HTML , is there any built-in way to do this? I've tried with some Blade methods like @string with no results

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solved it by extending Blade

I created a blade tag such as

```
@hardcodeConfig('siteName')
```

And in my blade_extensions I did this:

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('hardcodeConfig');
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all($pattern, $view, $matches);
    foreach($matches[2] as $index => $key){
        $key = str_replace([ "('", "')" ], '', $key);
        $configValue = \Config::get( $key );
        $view = str_ireplace($matches[0][$index], $configValue, $view);
    }
    return $view;
});
```

This does exactly was I was looking for, I created one for Config and another for Lang

Answer (score 0):

On your controller do this

```
$siteName = Config::get('app.siteName');
View::make('xxx', array('siteName' => $siteName))
```

for example

And you will be able to retrieve te variable siteName on your view with only

```
{{$siteName}}
```

Hope this will help (Or maybe I doesn't understand the problem)

Comment: That's not the problem because that will call to Config on every request, I want the siteName to be plain HTML in the views after they are compiled to /storage/views